# list.files() cannot get the correct list

Tags: r

I have a list of files function which looks like this:

`files <- rev( list.files( list.dirs( "../runs" ), "*.gene.read.count", full.names=TRUE ) )`

This produces the follow result:

```
> files
 [1] "../runs/Sample_7316/7316_AACCGA_L003_R.gene.read.count"                                
 [2] "../runs/Sample_7315/7315_GAATCT_L003_R.gene.read.count"                                
 [3] "../runs/Sample_7314/7314_CCTTGC_L003_R.gene.read.count"                                
 [4] "../runs/Sample_7313/7313_AGGCCA_L003_R.gene.read.count"                                
 [5] "../runs/Sample_7312/7312_GCGAAG_L003_R.gene.read.count"                                
 [6] "../runs/Sample_7311/7311_TCTCAG_L003_R.gene.read.count"                                
 [7] "../runs/Sample_7310/7310_CTCTGG_L003_R.gene.read.count"                                
 [8] "../runs/Sample_7309/7309_ATGGCG_L008_R.gene.read.count"                                
 [9] "../runs/project-043.Allreports/project043.raw.gene.read.count.hetro.homo.csv"          
[10] "../runs/project-043.Allreports/project043.raw.gene.read.count.csv"                     
[11] "../runs/project-043.Allreports/project043.gene.read.count.hetro.homo.csv"              
[12] "../runs/project-043.Allreports/project043.gene.read.count.csv"                         
[13] "../runs/project-043.Allreports/analysis-project043.raw.gene.read.count.html"           
[14] "../runs/project-043.Allreports/analysis-project043.raw.gene.read.count.hetro.homo.html"
[15] "../runs/project-043.Allreports/analysis- project043.gene.read.count.html"              
[16] "../runs/project-043.Allreports/analysis-project043.gene.read.count.hetro.homo.html"
```

the problem is that i only need the files inside the dirs starting with Sample_73

I tried many different things but nothing works for me:
`files <- rev( list.files( list.dirs( "../runs/Sample*" ), "*.gene.read.count", full.names=TRUE ) )`

Hope that there is a way to only select these directories:

```
 [1] "../runs/Sample_7316/7316_AACCGA_L003_R.gene.read.count"                                
 [2] "../runs/Sample_7315/7315_GAATCT_L003_R.gene.read.count"                                
 [3] "../runs/Sample_7314/7314_CCTTGC_L003_R.gene.read.count"                                
 [4] "../runs/Sample_7313/7313_AGGCCA_L003_R.gene.read.count"                                
 [5] "../runs/Sample_7312/7312_GCGAAG_L003_R.gene.read.count"                                
 [6] "../runs/Sample_7311/7311_TCTCAG_L003_R.gene.read.count"                                
 [7] "../runs/Sample_7310/7310_CTCTGG_L003_R.gene.read.count"                                
 [8] "../runs/Sample_7309/7309_ATGGCG_L008_R.gene.read.count"
```

Comment: `grep("Sample_73", files, value=TRUE)` ought to do it

Comment: Yess that should do that hehe, but it should be nice if it can be done within 1 call:)

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw Sometimes one-liners can actually make the code harder to read.

Comment: @user1477388 Maybe youre right i know it can be done with a system call in one line which looks very simple. But unfortunatly the output can differ per system and we want to have to code as transparent as possible.

Comment: If you really want one line: `files <- grep("Sample_73", rev( list.files( list.dirs( "../runs" ), "*.gene.read.count", full.names=TRUE ) ), value=TRUE)`

Comment: @hrbrmstr Yes, this is also a possible option indeed, thanks for the answer, i was hoping that it was possible within the list.files option but indeed this works as well.

Comment: how about `files <- rev( list.files( list.dirs( "../runs" ), ".gene.read.count|Sample_73", full.names=TRUE ) )`?

Comment: @Jase_ No this is not working. gives a longer list as the previous function :) but thanks anyway!

Comment: try this `files <- rev( list.files( list.dirs( "../runs" ), "(Sample_73)(.gene.read.count)", full.names=TRUE ) )`

Comment: @Jase_ Sorry also not working ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.files` will not match the pattern to the full file name. Similar to the comments above, an alternative is to apply `grep` to the results, or apply it to the list of paths you give as argument, like:

```
files <- rev( list.files( grep( "Sample_73", list.dirs( "../runs" ), value=TRUE), "*.gene.read.count", full.names=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by celiomsj, the `pattern` argument of `list.files` only matches on the filename, not the path, so this is best done in two lines.  The answer below uses `str_detect` as a more readable alternative to `grepl`.

```
library(stringr)
files <- list.files(
  "../runs",
  pattern    = glob2rx("*.gene.read.count"),
  full.names = TRUE, 
  recursive  = TRUE
)
files <- files[str_detect(files, fixed("Sample_73"))]
```